# solrj atomic update - how to set field to null?

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using atomic update with Solrj. It works perfectly, but I don’t know how to delete a field within an existing document.

In the Solr tutorial (http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) they explain how to do it with the xml:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="employeeId">05991</field>
    <field name="skills" update="set" null="true" />
  </doc>
</add>
```

Does anyone knows how to do it from SolrJ?

Thanks!

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234045/solr-how-to-use-the-new-field-update-modes-atomic-updates-with-solrj, might this help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. So apparently this is the way to do so -

```
  SolrInputDocument inputDoc = new SolrInputDocument();

  Map<String, String> partialUpdateNull = new HashMap<String, String>();
  partialUpdateNull.put("set", null);

  inputDoc.setField("FIELD_YOU_WANT_TO_DELETE", partialUpdateNull);
```

Thanks anyways!